# WPF Pie Chart Label Issue

Tags: wpf, wpftoolkit

I am using Labeled Pie Chart in WPF application.The pie chart labels are appearing twice.Please find the attached screenshot.
[![enter image description here][1]][1]

Offline-8 is the only label that should appear.
Please find the code below

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:CentralPiePanel}" x:Key="pieChartLabelDataTemplate">
        <Border BorderThickness="0" BorderBrush="White">
            <StackPanel Background="White" Orientation="Horizontal">

                <!--<TextBlock Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type customcontrols:PieChartLabel}},Path = FormattedRatio}" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="5,0,5,0">

                </TextBlock>-->

                <!--<TextBlock Text=" - "></TextBlock>-->

                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Key}" Margin="0,0,5,0"></TextBlock>
                <TextBlock Text="-"></TextBlock>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Value}" Margin="0,0,5,0"></TextBlock>


            </StackPanel>

        </Border>


    </DataTemplate>


enter code here

    <customcontrols:LabeledPieChart Loaded="EGMLabelChart_Loaded" Height="270"  x:Name="ControllerLabelChart" BorderThickness="0"    Grid.Column="0" BorderBrush="White" Margin="2 2 2 2" Palette="{StaticResource OnlineOfflineStatusPalette}">
        <interactivity:Interaction.Triggers>
            <interactivity:EventTrigger EventName="MouseLeftButtonUp">
                <interactivity:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding PieSelectionChangeCommand}" CommandParameter="{x:Static dashboard:PieType.CONTROLLERS}"/>
            </interactivity:EventTrigger>
        </interactivity:Interaction.Triggers>
        <customcontrols:LabeledPieSeries x:Name="ControllerLabelPieSeries" Margin="0" ItemsSource="{Binding ControllersStatus}" IndependentValueBinding="{Binding Key}" DependentValueBinding="{Binding Value}"
                                         IsSelectionEnabled="True" PieChartLabelStyle="{StaticResource pieChartLabelStyle}" PieChartLabelItemTemplate="{StaticResource pieChartLabelDataTemplate}"
                                         LabelDisplayMode="Connected"></customcontrols:LabeledPieSeries>

    </customcontrols:LabeledPieChart>
```

Comment: Even though you have code comment out, remove it altogether. Just in case its playing a part (somehow). Also can you show us the wpf where you are using that data template

Comment: please check the edited code